# C++: Sharing an object between two other objects

Tags: c++, object, reference, share, initializer-list

There are 1 main class and 3 classes: `Main`, `MLME`, `MAC` and `Network`.

I would want an MLME object to be created within the MAC object upon calling the constructor of the MAC. Then share the same object to the Network object when calling the Network constructor.

This without making the MLME object global or allocating memory with `malloc()` or `new`.

I believe this should be done with references which I don't understand fully. Also there might have to be some initializer-list in `Network.cpp`? I am more experienced with C than C++ and have tried a lot in order to understand all of this.

This is some of my thoughts of the structure, header and cpp files:

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "MAC.h"
#include "Network.h"

int main() {

    MAC mac();
    Network network(mac);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the MLME part to be shared:

**MLME.h**

```
#ifndef MLME_H_INCLUDED
#define MLME_H_INCLUDED

class MLME {
public:
    MLME();
};

#endif
```

**MLME.cpp**

```
#include "MLME.h"

MLME::MLME() {}
```

The MAC class:

**MAC.h**

```
#ifndef MAC_H_INCLUDED
#define MAC_H_INCLUDED

#include "MLME.h"

class MAC {
private:
    MLME mlme; // NULLED ?
public:
    MAC();
MLME getMLME();
};

#endif
```

**MAC.cpp**

```
#include "MAC.h"

MAC::MAC() {
    mlme = MLME:MLME();
}

MLME MAC::getMLME() {
    return mlme;
}
```

The Network class:

**Network.h**

```
#ifndef NETWORK_H_INCLUDED
#define NETWORK_H_INCLUDED

#include "MLME.h"

class Network {
private:
    MLME& mlme;
public:
    Network(MAC mac);
};

#endif
```

**Network.cpp**

```
#include "Network.h"

class MAC;

Network::Network(MAC mac) {
    mlme = mac.getMLME();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but:

- The `Network::Network` constructor should take `MAC` by reference, like so: `Network::Network(MAC& mac)`. Currently you take a copy, which means taking a copy of `MLME` as well.
- In addition, the `Network::Network` constructor should use an initializer list to initialize `mlme`. So the full form would be:

```
Network::Network(MAC& mac) : mlme(mac.getMLME()) {}
```

- `MAC::getMLME()` should return a reference to `MLME`: `MLME& MAC::getMLME()`. Otherwise you return a copy.
- The explicit construction of `MLME` in the `MAC` constructor is not needed: it is already default-constructed.
- You may want to prevent copying of `MLME` instances by saying `MLME(const MLME&) = delete`. If it is really a shared resource, you want any changes to go back to the shared instance. Making it impossible to copy `MLME` instances will prevent you from accidentally making or modifying a copy.
- In your main function: `MAC mac()` does not do what you think it does. Remove the `()` or you get a "most vexing parse" error.

Comment: Thank you! The only confusion for me is the prevention of copying `MLME` instances by saying `MLME(const MLME&) = delete`, could you explain more of that in your answer? Then I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

**Main.cpp**

```
int main() {

    MAC mac;
    Network network(mac);

    mac.set(10);

    mac.print();
    network.print();

    mac.set(11);

    mac.print();
    network.print();

    return 0;
}
```

**MLME.h**

```
#ifndef MLME_H_INCLUDED
#define MLME_H_INCLUDED

#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

class MLME {
private:
    int i;
public:
    MLME();
    void print();
    void set(int in);
};

#endif
```

**MLME.cpp**

#include "MLME.h"

```
MLME::MLME() {}

void MLME::print() { cout << 'i' << i << endl; }

void MLME::set(int in) {
    i = in;
}
```

**MAC.h**

```
#ifndef MAC_H_INCLUDED
#define MAC_H_INCLUDED

#include "MLME.h"

class MAC {
private:
    MLME mlme; // NULLED ?
public:
    MAC();
    MLME& getMLME();
    void print();
    void set(int in);
};

#endif
```

**MAC.cpp**

```
#include "MAC.h"

MAC::MAC() {
    mlme = MLME();
}

MLME& MAC::getMLME() {
    return mlme;
}

void MAC::print() {
    mlme.print();
}

void MAC::set(int in) {
    mlme.set(in);
}
```

**Network.h**

```
#ifndef NETWORK_H_INCLUDED
#define NETWORK_H_INCLUDED

#include "MAC.h"

class Network {
private:
    MLME& mlme;
public:
    Network(MAC& mac);
    void print();
};

#endif
```

**Network.cpp**

```
#include "Network.h"

Network::Network(MAC& mac) : mlme(mac.getMLME()) {}

void Network::print() {
    mlme.print();
}
```

**output**

```
i10
i10
i11
i11
```

Comment: Some descriptive text is always preferred, or even a must, in this forum. Even if I can understand your code.